# C++ Templates & Inheritance in Java

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics, inheritance

I have the following classes in C++

```
ParentClass
{
  virtual int MyMethod();
}

class ExistingOne : ParentClass {...}

class ExistingTwo : ParentClass {...}
```

Now I would like to create a class that can extend either of the Existing classes and override a couple of their methods plus call a method in the Existing class under some conditions.

In C++ this is done using the following:

```
template< class BaseTemplate >
class MyClass : public BaseTemplate
{
  int MyMethod()
  {
    DoSomething();
    return BaseTemplate::MyMethod();
  }
}
```

How is this done in Java?

So far I have

```
public abstract class ParentClass
{
  public abstract int MyMethod();
}

public class ExistingOne extends ParentClass {...}

public class ExistingTwo extends ParentClass {...}

public class MyClass<T extends ParentClass>
{
  public int MyMethod()
  {
    DoSomething();
    return T.MyMethod();  //MyMethod must be statically defined? 
  }
}
```

Oh and lastly, I cannot modify the "Existing" or Parent class.

So is this the correct approach? How do I solve the static requirement?

Comment: Java has poor capabilites about _'generic'_ classes and interfaces as compared to c++ AFAIR.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this is not about *poor capabilites*, it is just wrong design.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It was just an opinion thrown in. It may be well true what you say ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ well, IMO your opinion looks more like a rant about Java. If that wasn't your intention, please consider to remove the comment or edit it accordingly.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It's not really a rant, but one of the reasons I prefer c++ over java. They have their certain places in various problem domains. I'm just stating, that straightforward metaprogramming isn't one of the strengths of java programming (though this is of less importance in the java environment at all).

Answer (score 2):

In the C++ class definition, `MyClass` extends `BaseTemplate`. In the Java example, `MyClass` doesn't extend `ParentClass`, thus getting the expected problem.

In Java, just change the definition to:

```
public class MyClass<T extends ParentClass> extends ParentClass {
    @Override
    public int MyMethod() {
        DoSomething();
        return super.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

---

Since `MyMethod` is abstract in `ParentClass`, this gives a compiler error. Instead, you would need to call `MyMethod` from an instance of `ParentClass`. This can be fixed by having a field `T t` inside `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass<T extends ParentClass> extends ParentClass {
    T t;
    public MyClass(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
    @Override
    public int MyMethod() {
        DoSomething();
        return t.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, using generics and extending `ParentClass` here won't have any sense at all.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.  However calling super.MyMethod() has the issue of Cannot directly invoke the abstract method MyMethod() for the type ParentClass.  Secondary to that, in C++ the method called would be the template's not the parent's method.

Comment: You're on the right track, but this has some errors in it if you use his ParenClass definition above ... consider polishing?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza So MyClass will have an instance of T and doesn't need to extend ParentClass anymore?

Comment: @user3581890 yes, you could remove it. Unless you have non-abstract methods in `ParentClass` that you can use in `MyClass`.